# Was Middle English or something like it spoken during the late Anglo-Saxon period?

Tags: old-english, middle-english

As far as I've been able to determine from Wikipedia and Googling (I'm not a linguist), Old English appears to have changed into Middle English very soon after the Norman Conquest (around the end of the 11th century or the beginning of the 12th). However, it seems to me just a few generations aren't enough for the dramatic changes in language between Middle and Old English to occur.

This to me indicates that Middle English was already spoken before the Norman Conquest, and Old English was only the formal version of the language, kept alive by the written word. Is there any evidence in favour or against this?

Comment: This might get better response on the linguistics SE.

Comment: The changes happened over several centuries. But there was a dearth of writing in English after the conquest for a bit, and when it resumed, it was updated to match where the language was. That gave the appearance of greater change. Many changes we are familiar with from ME had already started in late Old English writing, such as simplification of unstressed vowels and endings.

Comment: This always happens after a conquest grows a top layer of the conquering language over a base of the original language. Around half of English words come from Latin or French, with several layers of growths. All happening in different ways to different people at different times in different places, all over England. For around half a millennium, until printing set in and we got Middle English spelling.

Comment: "...Middle English was already spoken before the Norman Conquest"... that's just not applicable to how the label is defined. OE from 400AD-1066, ME 1066- 1475, ModE, 1475- now. So -by definition- it can't have been spoken before 1066. So maybe you're thinking that some -features- of ME started before 1066. That may well be the case, but surely the great majority of changes from OE to ME were entirely caused by French. But then the feature that changed before 1066 would be still, -by definition- part of OE. That's how the labels work.

Comment: I don't think it's just a matter of labelling. Old English is unintelligible if you're not used to it; it barely looks like English. Middle English, on the other hand, is somewhat comprehensible, if only just.

Comment: The dominant form of written middle English (as recorded from the 14th century on) was based on the dialect of the East Midlands, while many of the notable Anglo-Saxon writers, like Caedmon and Bede, were based in Northumbria, or otherwise in distant monasteries. So it's possible the Old English dialects of the Midlands and South East were closer to Middle English than that of Northumbria. Although the French influence, changes in orthography, the temporary loss of English as a high status language and subsequent spread of vernacular forms, etc, all had effects.

Comment: Do we have an idea of what the spoken language would've looked like at the time of the Norman Conquest? That should give some kind of clue as to the answer to the question.